# Is this a valid usage of "forget about" - "X can't afford three meals a day, forget about sanitary living conditions"

Tags: sentence-patterns, subcontinental-english, complex-sentences

I was trying to cobble together a sentence expressing the idea above, that:

> **something doesn't do X, and so, definitely doesn't do Y (which is harder than X).**

I grew up using ", forget about" to express such constructions - but upon Googling (this form is tough to google for), I could only find this [link to the Times of India](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/tv/news/hindi/exclusive-sonali-phogat-after-being-evicted-from-bigg-boss-14-rubina-dilaik-doesnt-even-let-her-husband-speak-forget-about-others/articleshow/80449716.cms):

> Rubina Dilaik doesn't even let her husband speak, forget about others:

This makes me suspect that this could be an Indianism that I grew up with.

How are thoughts such as those above expressed in standard English? I'd appreciate a few more links or definitions if "forget about" is indeed an acceptable phrase.

I feel like some alternative *"conjunctive phrases"* (not the correct term) that could replace "forget about" could rely on terms such as "not least", "least of all", "definitely not", etc. ...

Comment: This is yet another variant of [_let alone_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/319151/15299).

Comment: @JohnLawler Indeed so, as too are many related questions [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/29878), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/124358), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/162675), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/248736), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/258360), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/272374), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/319149), [8](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/457079), [9](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/503152).

Comment: That's why comments are simpler. Nobody ever looks for or finds Official Answers, because every question starts off with some egregious error, usually intoned with "As we know, ..." The SE model of Question-Answer does not work when questions are based on nonsense and answers are matters of opinion.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for surfacing the more common variant. Lighten up please! :) No clue what official answers are - nothing comes up on google.